ERC-20 Token Lookup
I am looking for an ERC-20 token with only the Name (Ticker), but when I search that up on Etherscan I come up with many many options.
Is there any way yo look these up by other criteria such as Transfers, Holder Allocation, ETC? This token is not listed in any CEX or DEX at this time as it is just a testing token.

Probably some service provides the querying features you need. Try to search for such services online - unfortunately, I can't give you any specific one.
